# Auto-generate HTML blog page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, blogs, auto-generate

So, I am creating a web page for a family member who has a very small business they want online.  I am pretty new to creating websites and so I am figuring out most of it on the fly.  I am using bootstrap for the site.

One of the parts needed for the site is a blog.  My question is how to go about creating some sort of way to generate a new blog page.  They have no real computer expertise outside of an average user.  So I need to create a way to allow them to type what they need for the blog, and then have the site generate a new, pre-formatted blog page.

I know this is done a lot and am sure there is a standard way of doing this, but I couldn't find any explanation of how to do it.  I have thought of creating a separate program to create the page.  Or maybe I should do this with javascript?  Not sure what the standard way to do this is and was hoping that somebody could just point me in the right direction.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=blog+software

Answer (score -1):

Simple way to create a page using PHP

```
$myFileName = "myfilename.php"; //      or .html $f = fopen($myFileName, 'w'); $Data = "your html code or php code goes here"; fwrite($f, $Data); fclose($f);
```